# Generate GraphQL shema from typescript resolvers?

Tags: typescript, graphql, node-modules, code-generation

I've found many ways to generate TypeScript types from my graphql interface schema but I find this all kind of pointless. I figure I would write much less code if the types are just generated from my resolvers as they are the thing actually returning the type.

*Right now:*

```
# First make the graphql type
type Query {
    hello: String
}
```

```
// Then build the resolvers adhering to the graphql types
const resolvers: Resolvers = {
    Query: {
        hello: () => 'world!',
    },
}
```

*Instead why not just:*

```
// Build the resolvers
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        hello: () => 'world!',
    },
}
export type Resolvers = typeof resolvers
```

```
# Generated graphql schema from typescript 'Resolvers' type
[...]
```

It just seems really obvious and like it should be very popular but I can't find such a thing.
Is there a library that generates a GraphQL schema from my TypeScript resolvers in this way?